# How to get the Element value from returned Soap based XML Message

Tags: c#, xml

I am to get the element value of Soap based retuned XML as below.

### XML File:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendToDSSResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SendToDSSResult>
        <RC>0</RC>
        <RCD></RCD>
        <PCKT>
          <IDNO>1212</IDNO>
          <IDTYPE>051</IDTYPE>
          <NOBOX>121216</NOBOX>
          <NAME>James</NAME>
       </PCKT>
      </SendToDSSResult>
    </SendToDSSResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I want to get the values of IDNO, NoBox and Name. I am trying to use the following code below to get the values but it throws an Exception. What's the correct way to get the element values?

### C# Code:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(cleanXml); //OR XDocument.Load(filename)      
string Name = xDoc.Descendants("Name").First().Value;
```

Comment: "What's the correct way to get the element values?" : there is no correct way , only way is you have to parse it. that's all.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should add XNamespace and then you can read out the specific value from the nodes or tags under the node, try this demo in your ConsoleApplication:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/")+"NAME").First();
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Root` property.

```
string name = xDoc.Root.Descendants("NAME").First().Value;
```

Comment: It throws an invalid exception if I try to get the value like this exception details : (xDoc.Root.Descendants("NAME").First()' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException')

Comment: @OseeAliz : Please Do Some work and let us know if you face any problem, otherwise it's difficult to SO users to resolve your issue.

Comment: @Sudhhakar Instead of being rude you can atleast post a solution as I have already posted the codes..